# DynamoDB. I just want to list items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, serverless

I am currently working myself through the very helpful [Serverless Stack Tutorial](https://serverless-stack.com/). In the tutorial, an AWS Lambda API to DynamoDB is made, with the Endpoints called "create", "get", "list" and so on.

Trying to implement the "get" function into my own project worked fine. (This function uses the `dynamoDbLib.call("get", params);` operation (I don't understand why it should not be `getItem` as in the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html)) I am using the template of this [chapter](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/setup-the-serverless-framework.html) and the lib-files of this [chapter](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-create-note-api.html).
But trying to use either `batchget` or `BatchGetItem` instead results in the following Error Message: `dynamoDb[action] is not a function`.

Just to make my intention clear: I just want to list all the Items of my table (and maybe specify a range of primary key values later). I tried adapting the "list" function of the [tutorial](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-list-all-the-notes-api.html), but the "query" action did not seem to be suitable, as the `"KeyConditionExpression": "string",` only allows primary keys to be compared with the equality operator (`=`). (Sort keys can be queried with `a between b and c` though).

Do you have any suggestions about how I should proceed?
The BatchGetItem operator is not ideal as well as I have to specify the items as an array and not as a numeric range!

Finally, this is the last status of the code:

```
    import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context, callback) {
    var params = {
        "RequestItems" : {
            "my-table-name" : {
                "ConsistentRead":false,
                "Keys":[{
                    "id":{
                        "N":"1",
                        "N":"2"
                    }
                }]

        }
        }


    };

    try {
        const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("BatchGet", params);
        if (result.Item) {
            // Return the retrieved item
            callback(null, success(result.Item));
        } else {
            callback(null, failure({ status: false, error: "Item not found." }));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
    }
}
```

Thanks for support and feedback, but don't be too hard on me with criticism since I consider myself as a noob!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to focus on is `DocumentClient` is different from `AWS.DynamoDB`

documentation says:

> The document client simplifies working with items in Amazon DynamoDB
>   by abstracting away the notion of attribute values.

`dynamoDb[action] is not a function` - means it doesn't have that function(try to add `batchGet` instead since the case sensitiveness).

I went through the documentation and found that documentation `documentclient` supports this functions:

- batchGet(params, callback)
- batchWrite(params, callback)
- createSet(list, options)
- delete(params, callback)
- get(params, callback)
- put(params, callback)
- query(params, callback)
- scan(params, callback)
- update(params, callback)

from : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

in order to take a list of items and take desired properties only, you can use `scan`.

```
const params = {
  ProjectionExpression: 'id, name', // fields you need
  TableName: 'table_name'
};

try {
  const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("scan", params);
  // Return the list of items in response body
  callback(null, success(result.Items));
} catch (e) {
  callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
}
```

hope this will help you. feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: That made everything clear! Thx a lot. The filtering works as well btw

Comment: Can you help me with finding resources? I am failing at bringing my queries into my API functions. The Serverless Stack Tutorial only shows how to use pathParameters.

Comment: Hi, I could help you if you can provide more details about the question. perhaps you can create a question about where you are stuck.